# Using APNs new method in PHP without curl

Tags: php, stream, apple-push-notifications

I send apple push in php using stream with the old method (binary provider api), which will be closed soon.

So I try to use the new method based on http/2. I can send push notification using curl, but it's very slow. So I'd like to know if it is possible to do the same using stream, to be apple to keep the connexion alive and send more than one push for one connexion.

I can find example in java, in node.js, in go, but not in php.

Thanks for your help

Vincent